# How can i deploy my angular universal app on Namcheap hosting

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, namecheap

I just build an angular universal app and i now want to deploy it to namecheap hosting. I have copied the dist folder to public_html directory on the server i have created node app in same directory but now i dont know what next i should do. I am stucked

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

if your backend have in node.js then it is not possible to deploy in shared server. You need to deploy on VPS or any private server. And you have to run your Angular app by using node.js.

And your app have to setup like this. [enter link description here](https://github.com/souravgolui/matDash/tree/development)

and just run server.js using PM2 on VPS

Comment: My backend is PHP not node. and i can use node on my shared hosting as well

Comment: Then  how did you run node.js in shared server ?

Comment: Do you have root access on that server ? because to run node js you have to run `node example.js`